# Create Spring Boot WAR project and access rest layer declared as dependency

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat, spring-batch

I have created a Spring Boot Project(`Project-WAR`) with `WAR` packaging type, without any java code. In the pom file of this project I have declared the dependency of another Spring Boot Project(`Project-REST`) that exposes REST services.

When I deploy the WAR file of `Project-WAR` in Tomcat I want to be able to access the REST services layer exposed in `Project-REST` (that is included as dependency on `Project-WAR`). 
In other words I need to know if it is possible to access the REST services layer doing for ex: `localhost:8080/pathToRestService` ?

Comment: Why would you have a separate maven project for building the war file?

Comment: I have three projects: 
Project-DataModel
Project-Services
Project-REST

The first project has jar packaging. The second project has the dependency of the first project and third project has the dependency of the second project. I have to define packaging type for Project-Service and Project-REST as pom because maven does not let me build these two projects because of Compilation error